# reduce CSS rules to their lowest common denominator

Tags: php, css, optimization, minify

I have a templating engine in PHP wich allows you to set style attributes to objects prior to rendering.

During development time, I want these attributes to be inline so I can find them and change them easily. However, for production, I want to extract them and cache them in a css file. I also want to extract inline styles from any html element in the template.

The extracting, as well as ordering in arrays part is done. So I have a bunch or arrays that are structured as follow

```
array(
    'tag'  =>'div',
    'id'   =>'myDiv',
    'class'=>array('container','wrapper'),
    'style'=>array('background'=>'#CCCCCC',/*rules...*/)
);
```

Note that 'id' and 'class' keys are not necessarily set on all elements, but at least one of both is always set.

The part that renders this array as a css file is also done.

What I need to do is re-shuffle around the 'style' part of the array so common elements are grouped together. Optimization is not an issue since this process will be called only once then cached.

But I tried to design some pseudo-code and I'm just stuck. I am guessing that some part of the process at least will have to make "as-smart-as-possible guesses", but even that I don't see clearly.

Last recourse would be to just create the full string, then run the string itself through a css-minifier, but as far as what I could read, none does this "reducing to the lowest common denominator" thing.

Any suggestion?

**[edit]**

In answer to comments, here is more clarification:

if my array is presented like so:

```
array(
    array(
        'tag'  =>'div',
        'id'   =>'myDiv',
        'style'=>array('background'=>'#CCCCCC','font-size'=>'24px','color'=>'#FF0000')
    ),
    array(
        'tag'  =>'div',
        'class'=>array('container','hasBorder'),
        'style'=>array('background'=>'#CCCCCC','border'=>'1px solid black')
    ),
    array(
        'tag'  =>'div',
        'class'=>array('wrapper','hasBorder'),
        'style'=>array('color'=>'#FF0000','border'=>'1px solid black')
    )
);
```

My CSS should be rendered as such:

```
#myDiv{font-size:24px;}
#myDiv, .container{background:#CCCCCC;}
#myDiv, .wrapper{color:#FF0000;}
.hasBorder{border:1px solid black}
```

The output could be different; I don't care what the exact logic for defining how rules are set is; But what I want to avoid is what I currently have:

```
#myDiv{background:#CCCCCC;font-size:24px;color:#FF0000;}
.container{background:#CCCCCC;border:1px solid black;}
.wrapper{color:#FF0000';border:1px solid black;}
```

This is a simple example, but I have lots of repeated rules all over that make no sense; the generated CSS is not only bloated, it is not humanely maintainable. What I want is to generate a base CSS that designers can use to work with.

Comment: What exactly should this reduction do? Can you provide some example input/output?

Comment: You could separate entirely and use [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: Also, why don't you just use Firebug or Chrome Console to prototype CSS?

Comment: Inerdia: check the edited question
Jared Farrish: Using firebug or chrome console isn't relevant; I am creating a sort of templating engine where you could design on the fly in the template, but for the production site, I want to extract that css data and store it in a file. I need this process to be automated. As for LessCss, it's also not what I need since I am starting with a PHP array. Less allows for nesting, but what I need is sort of "non-nested,repeated css rules" to become "nested"

Answer (score 1):

css lint http://csslint.net/
watch out, she'll hurt your feelings

Comment: CssLint is a profiler, but what I need is to automate the process of generating css content

Comment: csslint will minimize your styles if you let it. and i didn't see anything about generating content up there. there's plenty of lorem-ipsum or spinoff generators out there. just copy and paste. same for images.

Comment: Sorry about the "generating css content" part, that was unclear; what I mean is I need to process my css rules server-side. Not minimizing, but finding the common part between different css rules. I want no human interaction involved, this has to be an automated process.